H@lp with OpenCV python
import numpy as np
import cv2


def initialize_face():
    cascade = '/Users/gadziaskarov/Desktop/py.projects/script_SO2/main.xml'

    clf = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    while True:
        _, frame = camera.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = clf.detectMultiScale(

            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30,30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            
        )
        for (x,y, width, height) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255, 255, 0), 2)
        
        cv2.imshow('Faces', 'frame')

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        

def main():
    initialize_face()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The error looks like this:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'

Overload resolution failed:

mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'


i dont even know what to do, so...

Please do not swap out letters to bypass Stack Overflow's quality control.

Every question here is a request for help, and the OpenCV tag tells us it's about OpenCV, so the current title tells us nothing. More importantly, it also says nothing to people who find this knowledge base entry in search results, and those people are our real customers here.

You are passing a string instead of the image as a parameter.
        cv2.imshow('Faces', 'frame')

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

Remove the quotation marks around "frame" :
        cv2.imshow('Faces', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

